# Let the camera work correctly with flash plugin in meteor

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, camera, meteor

I can not let the camera work in OSX Safari. Because it cannot use getusermedia I do not see any other option then using flash to access the camera.

The problem is the examples that I can find do not work in meteor.

Anyone do have a direction that I can follow or other approaches that the camera works in OSX Safari?

This is the library that I used: https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam

Here is the example

**client/safari.html**

```
<template name="safari">
    {{onLoad}}
    <div id="webcam"></div>
    <div>
        <h3>Available Cameras</h3><ul id="cams"></ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="capture">Make Video</button>
</template>
```

**client/safari.js**

```
Template.safari.onLoad = function() {
        $("#webcam").webcam({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            mode: "callback",
            swffile: "/jscam_canvas_only.swf", // canvas only doesn't implement a jpeg encoder, so the file is much smaller

            onTick: function(remain) {

                if (0 == remain) {
                    $("#status").text("Cheese!");
                } else {
                    $("#status").text(remain + " seconds remaining...");
                }
            },

            onSave: function(data) {
                debugger;
                var col = data.split(";");
            // Work with the picture. Picture-data is encoded as an array of arrays... Not really nice, though =/
            },

            onCapture: function () {
                webcam.save();

              // Show a flash for example
            },

            debug: function (type, string) {
                // Write debug information to console.log() or a div, ...
            },

            onLoad: function () {
            // Page load
                var cams = webcam.getCameraList();
                for(var i in cams) {
                    $("#cams").append("<li>" + cams[i] + "</li>");
                }
            }
        });
}

var filter_id = 0;

function changeFilter() {
 if (filter_on) {
 filter_id = (filter_id + 1) & 7;
 }
}

Template.safari.events = {
    'click #capture': function (e) {
        webcam.capture();
        changeFilter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post those examples and tell why didn't they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the irc channel of #meteor I found the solution.

Template.safari.onload needs to be Template.safari.rendered

And the swf file needs to be in the public folder in the root. Where all resource files needs to be.

Beginner mistakes but I learned a lot.